# Force to use a quality level in HLS using VideoJS

Tags: javascript, http-live-streaming, video.js, http-streaming, hls.js

In HLS using videoJS, I would like to know how can I force to use in the beginning (for firsts fragments) a specific variation (quality level) from a master playlist.

Answer (score 0):

use `videojs-contrib-quality-levels`

And use the bitrate based on your requirements.

```
player.qualityLevels().on('addqualitylevel', (event: any) => {
  const qualityLevel = event.qualityLevel;
  qualityLevel.enabled = qualityLevel.bitrate >= 496000;
});
```